# Regarding the meaning of the off-diagonal terms of the stress-energy tensor

Tags: general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

It's often stated that the off-diagonal terms in the stress-energy tensor signify shear while the diagonal terms are normal pressure terms (you get a displacement in the direction you apply pressure). I was reading Weinberg and I found this expression of the stress-energy tensor:

$$T(\alpha,\beta)=\sum_n P_n(\alpha) \frac{dx_n(\beta)}{dt} \delta^3(x-x_n(t)),$$ where $P_n$ is the 4-momentum of the $n$th particle and $x_n$ is it's $4$-position
Can someone help me with how does this definition reduce to the above-known facts that I mentioned?

Comment: For some reason, I can't put in the image. The expression is- T(alpha,beta)=Sum over n [P_n(alpha)*(dx_n(beta)/dt)*delta^3(x-x_n(t))], where P_n is the 4-momentum of the nth particle and x_n is it's 4-position.

Comment: Images of formulae are not approved. You need to use mathjax. I made a stab at it which should help you to see what to do, but I don't have the source and I don't think the result makes sense. In the meantime, I am voting to close. Please edit so that your question makes sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intuitive understanding of the elements in the stress-energy tensor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/184042/intuitive-understanding-of-the-elements-in-the-stress-energy-tensor)